# Загрузить данные в DataFrame из List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть список словарей. Каким образом загрузить его в `pandas.DataFrame()`?

```
[{'waitforunload_duration': 0, 'turnround_duration': 24.883333333333333, 'time_end': '08.09.2020 05:54:23'}, {'waitforunload_duration': 0, 'turnround_duration': 24.35, 'time_end': '08.09.2020 06:19:35'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто передать этот список как есть при создании датафрейма, то вроде бы тоже все работает. У вас не так?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: data = [ 
   ...:     {'waitforunload_duration': 0, 
   ...:      'turnround_duration': 24.883333333333333, 
   ...:      'time_end': '08.09.2020 05:54:23'}, 
   ...:     {'waitforunload_duration': 0, 
   ...:      'turnround_duration': 24.35, 
   ...:      'time_end': '08.09.2020 06:19:35'} 
   ...: ] 

In [3]: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[3]: 
   waitforunload_duration  turnround_duration             time_end
0                       0           24.883333  08.09.2020 05:54:23
1                       0           24.350000  08.09.2020 06:19:35
```

Answer (score 2):

Такое представление [называется](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) `records`. Для того, чтобы работать с ним, требуется создать `pandas.DataFrame()`, а затем вызвать у него метод `from_records()`:

```
pd.DataFrame().from_records(resp)
```

Отметим, что данный объект -- это именно список словарей и он не является `json`, а значит его невозможно загрузить с помощью `pd.read_json(resp)`, поскольку работа в этом случае осуществляется со строками